# Is there any way to extends with a static method in Dart?

Tags: dart, oop

I want to tie the `CoreTheme` class to the `DarkTheme` and `LightTheme` children so that they share common attributes.

What is the best way or best practice to do this?
I need the method `getTheme` to be static.
But the way I configured it is not a signature that justifies extending.

CoreTheme.dart:

```dart
    abstract class CoreTheme {
      static const String fontFamily = "GoogleSans";
    }
```

DarkTheme.dart:

```dart
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import '/core/themes/core_theme.dart';
    
    class DarkTheme implements CoreTheme {
    
      static getTheme() {
        return ThemeData(
          brightness: Brightness.dark,
          colorSchemeSeed: Colors.lightBlue[900],
          fontFamily: CoreTheme.fontFamily,
        );
      }
    }
```

LightTheme.dart:

```dart
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import '/core/themes/core_theme.dart';
    
    class LightTheme implements CoreTheme {
    
      static getTheme() {
        return ThemeData(
          brightness: Brightness.light,
          colorSchemeSeed: Colors.lightBlue[400],
          fontFamily: CoreTheme.fontFamily,
        );
      }
    }
```

Thank you! =)

Comment: If you mean how to minimize code duplication across  `DarkTheme.getTheme` and `LightTheme.getTheme`, you could add a `static ThemeData getTheme(Brightness brightness) => ThemeData(brightness: brightness, ...);` to `CoreTheme` (or as a freestanding function).

Comment: Oh, yes, jamesdlin you are right, but the classes will have many other differents codes. Thank you for the contribution.